# Language bar missing for only one language

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-registry, taskbar, language

I have two languages in the system: Japanese and Russian. Japanese does not displays in the old language bar, Russian does not displays on the default Language taskbar indicator.

`sfc /scannow` was done.

All upgrades installed. A lot of reboots. This happened after installing Insider Preview build from the stable version.

[image]
[image]

**Edit:** If delete Japanese and add another language without IME bot bars works find.

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Japanese** -> **Options** -> **Microsoft IME** -> **Options** -> **General** -> **Compatibility**. Change "*Use previous version of Microsoft IME*" to "**On**".